# Can't sign Ubuntu code of conduct

Tags: launchpad, development, gnupg

This is what I get when I type command to sign the Code of conduct for Launchpad.

```
clearsign failed: secret key not available
```

I followed steps from Launchpad but didn't get the confirmation e-mail from the launchpad servers, after uploading the key. That seems to be the missing bone here but I thought I could sign it with out those instructions.

*This is all I am doing :*

```
gpg --clearsign ./UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: ./UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0 (1).txt: clearsign failed: secret key not available
```

Launchpad instructs to do this but also as I said before it also said I would get an e-mail which I cannot find.

*Also when I do* :

```
gpg --fingerprint
```

I get no **output**.

Comment: Can you please include all steps you performed and the exact commands with their outputs to your question? It's very unclear what happened without that information.

Comment: The error message you're seeing means that gpg was unable to sign with your default key pair. Either you have no key pair, your default key pair has no private key, or it's a bug of some kind. Have a look at the GPG guide for launchpad and make sure you have everything set up correctly: https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey?action=show&redirect=ImportingYourOpenPGPKey

Comment: I added the Key ID to the /home/gnupg/gpg.conf before asking here, I tried all that is logical to try.

Comment: What's the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`? If it's empty you need to create or import a secret key (e. g. as per the instructions in Stefano's link).

Comment: @DavidFoerster My lauchpad account shows two keys and an ssh key. I'm using MATE

Comment: SSH keys are irrelevant here and in both cases Launchpad only knows the public part of the key. So far I've seen no proof or refute of whether you actually have a private GPG key. Please run the command and show its output like I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I only mentioned it (SSH) and didn't imply any relevance. The output is blank. How do I import the Keys I already made ? ( Post it as answer please ) Which Launchpad already has.

Comment: Do you have the secret key stored somewhere in a file that you could import? If not you'll have to make a new one and add it to Launchpad anew.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Liar

Comment: @DavidFoersterIt makes no sense! dude... I am following the Launchpad's instructions. I need not aggregate anything to the Question about those details since if anyone goes on that path then they could encounter this problem regardless of bleh blah.  I'm just going to start documenting all this non-sense, disregard Meta and report directly to Canonical. AskUBuntu should bot be an official channel anymore.

If you have no experience with the Ubuntu Code you should have no problem specifying it if you truly have a desire to honestly help.

Comment: People don't like to be called "liar" generally. We may have a misunderstanding or I might even be mistaken, but I didn't lie to you. Did you perform the steps in the sections “Creating your OpenPGP keys” of the Launchpad instructions? What was the result? Did you see your newly created key pair in the list?

Comment: Alternatively, if you went by “Creating your OpenPGP keys with gpg”, what was the result of `gpg --gen-key`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes that's what I can't believe. I'm following instructions step by step. And it shows how to create the keys. I'm stuck @ signing the code. Oh well I think that from the standpoint of gpg what you said is true. And that's where we are, after creating the keys with the GUI and since I introduced the post at the signing of the code of conduct I interpreted that you were saying that after following Launchpad's instructions I would still have to genetate another key despite me being following the instructions exactly. Would you agree that a mistake hard to get? I clearly couldn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42746/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-userdepth).

Comment: @David Foerster then I take that back. Let's put it as "I don't think that to be true" maybe you know that if I make a new key via terminal then the key will be known to gpg, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use **Seahorse** to *export* an ASC file.

Get the ID number for the key in the Seahorse program by click on the Key and choosing **properties**

Go to the ASC file's directory inside a terminal an do

```
gpg --import **keyname**.asc
```

Provide the passphrase

Now sign the Ubuntu code of conduct by providing the Key ID

```
gpg --clearsign --default-key **KEY_ID** UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt
```

Go to the signing page where the Launchpad platform will ask to paste the contents of the resulting signed key.

It will be the name as the original file but end with **ASC** extention.